# Duplicate contents of a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the following structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="abc" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="def" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="ghi" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option selected="selected">
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option>
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option>
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" checked="checked" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here all 3 columns of each row are similar elements respectively. I now want to copy the contents from the 1st td of all rows(all inputs made by the user) to the other 2 tds in 2nd and 3rd coloumn for all rows.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to start.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtb5Ldh1/).

Comment: you need to create a new row?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: No, I already have everything I need. I just need to copy the contents from 1st td to the other 2 tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  copy();
});

function copy() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td :input:not(:first)').val($(this).find('td :input:first').val()).prop('checked', $(this).find('td :input:first').prop('checked'))
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="abc" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="def" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="ghi" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option selected="selected">
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option>
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>
          123
        </option>
        <option>
          456
        </option>
        <option>
          789
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>
  Copy
</button>
```